# Error opening MainMenu.xib

Tags: objective-c, xcode

For the second time after I finished writing my application to reopen the project when I try to open the file MainMenu.xib:
The document "MainMenu.xib" could not be opened. The operation couldn’t be completed. *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil.

This is what appears in the console:


02/05/12 20:35:11,640 Xcode: Exception raised while decoding document objects - *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil
But if I build and run the application works fine.

Comment: Perhaps you (or your code) moved your xib file?

Comment: No, I have not moved anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem and I share in case others are in the same situation. The XIB file was not opened and seemed to be corrupt. I thought about what changes I made ​​recently. The last change was made ​​was the addition of sound to the buttons of the interface. In particular, I added a sound to put a checkbox in a table. To solve the problem I opened the XIB files as source code, then I found the line that contained the sound plugged in and I canceled. Now everything works as before. I hope I was helpful to someone.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a true hero of the Internet!